# How to create a stereoscopic 3d surface plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, stereoscopy, matplotlib-3d

I would like to be able to make 3D plots in matplotlib that can be displayed in stereoscopic 3D, like this:

[image]

The camera of the left image is slightly translated with respect to the right. If you practice for a bit, you can trick your brain into having your left eye look at the left image and your right eye at the right image and see 3D on any screen!

Anyway, I would like to be able to make any matplotlib 3d plot show up twice, with one camera slightly translated. I've managed to get just the plot itself in stereo, simply by translating the data:

```
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
axl = fig.add_subplot(1,2,1,projection='3d')
axr = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2,projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

axr.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
axl.plot_surface(X, Y-5, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
for ax in [axr,axl]:
    ax.set_zlim(-1.01, 1.01)
    ax.set_ylim(-10,10)
    ax.view_init(azim=10)
    ax.set_axis_off()
```

[image]

This gives the desired effect, but I would like to be able to also show the axes themselves in stereoscopic 3d. I can only find how to set the elevation and azimuth of the camera, using the `view_init` method of the Axes object. There doesn't seem to be a 'nice' way of translating the camera.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: what's wring with just setting, for example, `ax.view_init(azim = 10)` and `ax.view_init(azim = 20)` for your two subplots? I don't see why that is not "nice". Btw, you can also set the azimuth with `ax.azim = 10`, etc., which does the same thing, but is slightly shorter to write...

Comment: Mmm, actually you are right! Somehow I got it into my mind that translation is necessary to properly trick your brains, but there is actually nothing that is fundamentally different when rotating it.

Comment: The only wrong now is the axis labels. They are always printed horizontally...

Comment: that sounds like a different question - maybe start a new question with details of your label problems? You might start looking here first though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918380/rotating-axes-label-text-in-3d-matplotlib

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: I didn't, unfortunately.